# query user password to install application using LDAP

Tags: java, active-directory, spring-ldap, ldap-query

I want to remotely deploy an application to all the hosts under a DOMAIN CONTROLLER in an Active Directory Server using LDAP. I was able to get the details of all the hosts using the below code snippet:

```
searchFilter = (&(objectCategory=computer)(objectClass=computer))";
```

Then,I tried a JAVA code to fetch the passwords of the users,but the code returns password attribute as null.

```
 String filter = "(&(objectclass=person))";
   results = dirContext.search("", filter, controls);

      while (results.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult searchResult = (SearchResult) results.next();
        Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();

        NamingEnumeration<? extends Attribute> attrs = attributes.getAll();

        while (attrs.hasMore()) {
          System.out.println(attrs.next());
        }


        Attribute pwd = attributes.get("userPassword");
        if(pwd==null)
        {
            System.out.println("NullPointerException thrown!");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("=> userPassword : " + new String((byte[])pwd.get()));
        }
```

Is my approach to fetch passwords right or is there any other way to deploy an application for all the hosts under a DC??

Comment: Any system anywhere that can return user passwrods is badly broken. Don't rely on this behaviour. Find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Active Directory will not return the password which is encrypted and  which is usually in an attribute named unicodePwd. (vs [userPassword](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/UnicodePwd))

Answer (score 0):

The [`userPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f3adda9f-89e1-4340-a3f2-1f0a6249f1f8) attribute is really just a slightly easier to use synonym for the real password attribute, which is [`unicodePwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2). But both attributes are only ever used for changing or resetting the password. The documentation for `unicodePwd` says:

> The unicodePwd attribute is never returned by an LDAP search.

So you cannot do what you are attempting to do.

That's really how any good authentication system should work.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to deploy an application for all the hosts under a Domain Controller in AD??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Do you want to use AD for authentication in other applications?

Comment: I want to install an application to all the users under a host in a forest after successful AD authentication

Comment: Are you saying you want to install an application on the computer that a user logs into? You may be able to do that with a logon script. Search Google for ["install application logon script"](https://www.google.com/search?q=install+application+logon+script)